# How to overwrite measures at a line level in PowerPivot

Tags: microsoft-excel, powerpivot

I have two tables, each of the same dimension and same level of granularity;
Date, Site, Campaign, Ad Group, Keyword are the columns, with spend as the single measure.

What I am wanting to do is overwrite the spend data in one table, when the Site = "Yahoo". My question is,

a) Should I create a concatenated key and join these tables directly to overwrite spend?

b) Should I create multiple single column lookup tables (one for Site, one for Campaign, etc), and then join both of these tables to them so as to filter both tables at once?